# in app purchase in ios, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, ios5, in-app-purchase, exc-bad-access

I want to implement In-App-Purchase in my ios app, i have UPGRADE button, when user click on upgrade, I am sending product request using  SKPayment SKProductsRequest, and added its delegate methods,
the code is as shown below, whenever i click on upgrade button, after 2-3 seconds, it gives me error as 'executing bad access'. It giving error in sendRequest method only. Please give me the solution.

```
-(void)sendRequest
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {

        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"thisIsMyProdID"]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }
}
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Processing...");
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                //statusLabel.text = @"Done!";
                UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Complete"
                                    message:@"You have unlocked Feature 2!"
                                    delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                [tmp show];


            }
                               break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
            }
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here

            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        product = products[0];

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you shouldn't set a delegate to self without keeping a reference to your allocated object. This apply to both `SKProductsRequest *request` and `UIAlertView *tmp` : when you set delegate to self you should store the pointer somewhere (in some NSArray ?) in order to be able to unset the delegate on `dealloc`.

Comment: @Cœur I dont like to do it either but it works fine in general because alerts and requests and urlconnections are retained by iOS. AFAIK! you release it in the delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in my code, I not handled the object of SKPayment, so that before getting response from apple, my SKPayment object was released, so I got that bad access error, I declared the object globally and then its work fine. It was only my silly mistake, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since SKProductRequest is a subclass of SKRequest, you will want to implement the delegate

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

to get any errors, this will probably point you to the right place.  A good example is in the tutorial from raywenderlich.com (http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial).

Comment: yes, I already implemented that method, and it is not showing any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKPaymentQueue *skPaymentQueue;
```

You could keep the memory by define it as a property
in viewDidLoad

```
self.skPaymentQueue = [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue];
```